# Link Header Pagination - Dribbble API

Tags: pagination, dribbble-api

I am working with the Dribbble API and I do not understand their documentation in regards to Pagination: http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/#pagination

I've tried researching how to set this up but I can't seem to find information on how to use the Link header to set this up. This is the code I am using right now which works perfectly to pull in 12 recent shots, but I am stumped on pagination:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var url = 'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/user/shots?per_page=12&access_token=*removed*';
var $content = $('#dribbble');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $content.append('<div class="loading"><img src="./img/ajax-loader.gif" width="66" height="66" alt="Loading"></div>');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#loading').remove();
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var template = $('#dribbbleTpl').html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#dribbble').html(html).hide().fadeIn(400);
    },
    fail: function() {
        $content.append('<div class="error">Oops! Our Dribbble feed appears to be down.</div>');
    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Since you're requesting jsonp, the API should be returning the header meta data. This header will include your Link data. If you're not seeing the header in your response, try adding `&callback=foo` to your endpoint URL.